# How to make the citation of references as numbers in the text ? and with square brackets?

Tags: overleaf

in references.bib

```
@ARTICLE{2,
 AUTHOR={A. Gama  and Lazarevic Aleksandar and Latecki Longin Jan},
 TITLE={Machine Learning techniques},
 PUBLISHER={IEEE},
 ADDRESS={},
 YEAR={2007}
 }

@BOOK{3,
 AUTHOR={D.Hawkins},
 TITLE={Identification of Outliers},
 PUBLISHER={Springer},
 ADDRESS={},
 YEAR={1980}
 }
```

in another file: report.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}

%%-------------------------------------
%% Page margin settings - % half inch margin all sides (recommended)
%%-------------------------------------
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry} 

%%-------------------------------------
%% Font settings - % CM San or Ariel (recommended)
%%-------------------------------------
% Switch the following two line off: to revert back to default LaTex font (NOT recommended)
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

%%-------------------------------------
%% Math/Definition/Theorem/Algorithm packages settings 
%%-------------------------------------
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
\newtheorem{mytherm}{Theorem}

%%-------------------------------------
%% Algorithms/Code Listing environment settings  - 
%% Please do not change these settings
%%-------------------------------------
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0.1}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codeblue}{rgb}{0.10,0.00,1.00}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                        
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    frame=none
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}

%%-------------------------------------
%% Graphics/Figures environment settings
%%-------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%-------------------------------------
%% Table environment settings
%%-------------------------------------
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

%%-------------------------------------
%% List of Abbreviations settings
%%-------------------------------------
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{abbrv}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[abbrv,1]{label=,labelwidth=1in,align=parleft,itemsep=0.1\baselineskip,leftmargin=!}

\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.3}
%% \usepackage{setspace}
%%\doublespacing
%%-------------------------------------
%% Bibliography/References settings   - Harvard Style was used in this report
%%-------------------------------------
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref,url}
%\usepackage[comma,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{numbers}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} % DO NOT remove or switch of 

%%-------------------------------------
%% Appendix settings     
%%-------------------------------------
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%                     SETTING ENDS                                            %%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

 \mainmatter
    % Read for preparation of document in LaTex 
    % Lamport, L. (1986), LATEX: A Document Preparation System, Addison-Wesley.
    
    \input{chapters/introduction.tex}
    \input{chapters/literature.tex}% https://guides.library.bloomu.edu/litreview
    \input{chapters/methodology.tex}
    \input{chapters/results.tex}
    \input{chapters/discussion.tex}
    \input{chapters/conclusions.tex}
    \input{chapters/reflection.tex}
    

    
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Bibliography/References  -  Harvard Style was used in this report
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------
    %\bibliographystyle{unsrt} % Harvard Style 
    
    %\bibliography{references}  %  Patashnik, O. (1988), BibTEXing. Documentation for general BibTEX users.
    %\bibliographystyle{agsm}
    %\bibliographystyle{abbrv-fr}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{references}
    
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Appendices
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \begin{appendices}
        \input{chapters/appendix_A.tex}
        \input{chapters/appendix_B.tex}
    \end{appendices}
    
\end{document}

I have here this text 

In view of this, this is considered a very popular method \citep{2,3}.
```

I want it to be as:

In view of this, this is considered a very popular method [2,3].

and not  this :
In view of this, this is considered a very popular method (A. Gama  and Lazarevic Aleksandar: 2007 and Hawkins:1980)

it's giving me bunch of errors:

```
The compiler cannot find the file you want to include. Make sure that you have uploaded the file and specified the file location correctly.
Learn more
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

This compile didn’t produce a PDF. This can happen if:
There is an unrecoverable LaTeX error. If there are LaTeX errors shown below or in the raw logs, please try to fix them and compile again.
The document environment contains no content. If it’s empty, please add some content and compile again.
This project contains a file called output.pdf. If that file exists, please rename it and compile again.
```

and there's no package named numbers.sty and I'm overleaf so I've never installed a file

Thank you -

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: added the rest of code .. I tried many styles but not working

Comment: By default, the `plainnat` bibliography style tells BibTeX to produce numeric-style citation call-outs. If you would rather get authoryear-style citation call-outs, you need to load the `natbib` package with the option `authoryear`. Your code actually features the instruction `\usepackage[comma,authoryear]{natbib}`; however, for some unexplained reason it's commented out. Do activate that instruction and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: I want as numeric style as plainnat but I tried it and it's not working plus I've commented other packages \usepackage[comma,authoryear] because I don't want it only the numeric style is what I want

Comment: In that case, do run `\usepackage[comma,numbers]{natbib}` and perform a full recompile cycle.

Comment: I'm doing \citep{1} but it's showing [3]

Comment: @user4556432 -- Not knowing anything about the entry with key `1` -- so far, you've mentioned entries with keys `2` and `3`, but *nothing* about `1` -- or where in the document it gets cited, it is simply not possible to say anything useful.

Comment: is this really your answer !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!